# ps aux | grep searches in .bash_history file

Tags: bash, grep, ps

I have Debian8 (Jessie) running on my mcahine.

I run

```
$ ps aux | grep '[c]13dc8623fe6abc'
```

I get the following results

```
.bash_history:java -jar slave.jar -jnlpUrl http://tomcat-server:8080/slave-agent.jnlp -s c13dc8623fe6abc
.bash_history:java -jar slave.jar -jnlpUrl http://tomcat-server:8080/slave-agent.jnlp -s c13dc8623fe6abc   
Script/build.sh:java -jar slave.jar -jnlpUrl http://tomcat-server:8080/slave-agent.jnlp -s c13dc8623fe6abc
```

The results returned are search results from bash script files on my system. This is not what I expect at all. I would expect it to grep/search the output of `ps aux`.

Why is this strange behaviour happening in my system.?

As per the suggestion below, I have done the following

```
$ type ps
```

Output

```
::6+type ps
ps is /bin/ps

$ type grep
```

Output

```
::7+type grep
grep is aliased to `grep --color=auto -I -r --exclude=\*.{c.svn-base,o,.py,so*,a}'
```

After setting

```
$ PS4=':$BASH_SOURCE:$LINENO+'

$ set -x
```

After that If I do

```
$ ps aux | grep '[c]13dc8623fe6abc'
```

I get the following output.

```
::5+grep --color=auto -I -r '--exclude=*.c.svn-base' '--exclude=*.o' '--exclude=*..py' '--exclude=*.so*' '--exclude=*.a' '[c]13dc8623fe6abc'
::5+ps aux
.bash_history:java -jar slave.jar -jnlpUrl http://tomcat-server:8080/slave-agent.jnlp -s c13dc8623fe6abc
.bash_history:java -jar slave.jar -jnlpUrl http://tomcat-server:8080/slave-agent.jnlp -s c13dc8623fe6abc   
 Script/build.sh:java -jar slave.jar -jnlpUrl http://tomcat-server:8080/slave-agent.jnlp -s c13dc8623fe6abc
```

Comment: Run `PS4=':$BASH_SOURCE:$LINENO+'`, then `set -x`, then the same command again; if this returns anything other than `::3+ps aux` and `::3+grep '[c]13dc8623fe6abc'` on stdout (with potentially different line numbers, indicating how long your shell has been open), amend the question appropriately.

Comment: ...if you have a function or alias shadowing `ps`, that'll display what it's actually doing. Output of `type ps` or `type grep` -- showing which executables, functions, or similar are *actually* providing `ps` or `grep` for you -- may also be helpful.

Comment: Following those steps may help you build a reproducer -- right now, nobody else is going to be able to get those same results, making this arguably more of an individual support question than a software development one.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - Please see updates above.

Comment: (Aside: If your goal is to have a mutex -- ensuring that only one instance of a given process can run at a time -- this is the wrong way to do it; see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/045)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As we determined in comments, running this with `set -x` enabled showed that an alias was adding a bunch of extra complexity to your `grep` call.

To make this as robust as possible, let's both prevent the alias from executing (by using the `command` buildin), and explicitly specify that your grep should be searching stdin (by passing `-` as a filename, and using `-e` to flag the hex string that follows as unambiguously representing the target to search for):

```
ps aux | command grep -e '[c]13dc8623fe6abc' -
```

Comment: Just as a point of clarification, the alias added the `-r` option to grep which would cause `grep` to ignore stdin and instead search the file system.  +1.

Comment: @John1024, ...actually, I was on the wrong system when I looked at behavior and the man page there -- it's the MacOS one that doesn't have this bug; it's still present on GNU.